# What is the Time Complexity of the following algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm deep diving algorithms just to get better and was wondering if my assumption that the following algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2) given the following input of `[3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6]` and the targetSum input at: `10`. I understand that the single iteration through the array has a time complexity of O(n) but I'm wondering if that if statement there makes the entire algorithm O(n^2) as I stated. Just looking for general discussion! Thanks!

```
def twoNumberSum(array,targetSum):
    
    for x in array:
        num = targetSum - x
        if num in array and num != x:
            return [x,num]
    return []
```

Comment: @aroe Yup, if condition could find required num `(targetSum-x)`at the last index of the array

Comment: Because of short-circuiting, it would be better to reorder it as `if num != x and num in array:`

Comment: You could make it O(n) by changing the array to a set. Searching a set is amortized O(1).

Comment: @Barmar And then you can also make it short: `if x != num in array:` :-)

Comment: @Barmar I think average, not amortized.

Comment: @KellyBundy too short, IMHO :)

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly I should reverse the order of the if statement and that should give me O(n)? Or do I have to both reverse the order and make the array a set?

Comment: Reversing the order doesn't change the complexity, because whenever the `!=` condition is true it has to perform an O(n) search. Changing to a set improves the complexity.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, I'm actually not convinced that your reverse order is better. That way, you likely almost always have to test *both* conditions instead of only one.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, but the cheap test is first.

Comment: @Barmar I know. But "cheap" isn't "free".

Comment: It probably doesn't make much difference, since `x == num` will be rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for that input it's O(n^2). You can improve by converting the list into a set, The operation `n in my_set` has complexity O(1) so your code would be optimized to O(n) complexity.

Comment: *"for that input it's O(n^2)"* - For what input is it not?

Comment: is this because I wouldn't need the and clause in the if statement anymore?

Comment: the complexity for a set lookup is O( log(n) ) not O(1)

Comment: @RedaBourial Where did you get that idea?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c#L60C1-L104C1 . best case scenario is O(1) worst case is O(n). i said  something stupid about it being O(log(n)). my bad

Comment: The complexity of a lookup in Python sets is on Average O(1), you are right that in the worst-case scenario, it could get to O(n) but because of the way Python implements hashing in the set, this worst-case scenario is very rare to happen.